# Center content being pushed aside by :before

Tags: html, css

Run the snippet below... the two digits in Orange are not centered in their fields.
They get offset when I add the `:before` content. How can I elegantly get the digit to center again (preferably without using magic numbers).

```css
.container {
  background: #ededed;
  height: 4rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
 }
 
.number {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.digit:nth-last-of-type(3n):before {
  content: ",";
  right: 0.75em;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
 }
 
 .digit:nth-last-of-type(3n) {
  background: orange;
  }
 
 .digit {
  width: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.25em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.1em;
  background: white;
  color: black;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="number">
    <span class="digit">1</span>
    <span class="digit">9</span>
    <span class="digit">0</span>
    <span class="digit">1</span>
    <span class="digit">0</span>
    <span class="digit">0</span>
    <span class="digit">0</span>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As no one has explained why you need to position absolute: pseudo elements are appended to the start or end of the element so your centred text is actually working properly, if you don't want the pseudo element to take space, then you need to position it absolutely

Comment: @Pete Yeah, I should have just read up on the position values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position
relative: "the space given for the element in the page layout is the same as if position were static"
absolute: "no space is created for the element in the page layout"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `:before` absolute and digit relative to achieve this.

```css
.container {
  background: #ededed;
  height: 4rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
 }
 
.number {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.digit:nth-last-of-type(3n):before {
  content: ",";
  left: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
 }
 
 .digit:nth-last-of-type(3n) {
  background: orange;
  }
 
 .digit {
  width: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.25em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.1em;
  background: white;
  color: black;
position:relative;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="number">
    <span class="digit">1</span>
    <span class="digit">9</span>
    <span class="digit">0</span>
    <span class="digit">1</span>
    <span class="digit">0</span>
    <span class="digit">0</span>
    <span class="digit">0</span>    
  </div>
</div>
```